# Sunspot Solr order by score relevancy and second column not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, sunspot, sunspot-rails

I'm working with Sunspot & Mongoid. Inneed of sorting by relevancy (score) value, and then event date. To do this, you're supposed to do

```
Article.search do
  keywords params[:query]
  order_by :score, :desc
  order_by :article_date, :asc
end
```

but that doesn't work accordingly. It instead sorts by article_date. If I remove article_date, it sorts properly according to score. If I sort using article_date and another field, say title rather than score, it also works fine.

Here are my gem versions

Using sunspot (1.3.0) 
Using sunspot_rails (1.3.0) 
Using sunspot_mongoid (0.4.1) 
Using sunspot_solr (1.3.0)

I based my work on this example here: [Solr/Lucene is it possible to order first by relevance, and then by a second attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3705109/solr-lucene-is-it-possible-to-order-first-by-relevance-and-then-by-a-second-att) and also the documentation of sunspot http://sunspot.github.com/sunspot/docs .

Any idea?

**[update]**

Thinking this might be related to me looping the results and not hits, I tried both scenarios:

```
Post.search.results.each do |result|
AND
Post.search.each_hit_with_result do |hit, result|
```

Alas, same thing.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?  I can't get `order_by :score, :desc` to work period.

Comment: @SarahVessels Unfortunately no :(. Sorry